# How can i itenerate int´s and insert into sql

Tags: python

Im trying to use a for loop the get the Id´s and update in the table the state of the product. Right now have this code:

```
for row in range(self.tableLinhaNova.rowCount()): 

    _item = self.tableLinhaNova.item(row, column) 
    if _item:            
        items1 = self.tableLinhaNova.item(row, column).text()
        items= int(items1)
    
    for item in items:
       cursor.execute("""UPDATE "Teste" SET "Estado"= 2 WHERE "IdTeste" = %s""",[item])
     
       
       con.commit()
```

Items is some Id´s like:

`18,17,83,14`

But it doesn´t work, i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I´m new in python, so i probably did something wrong can anyone help please!.

Comment: In English, the subjective form of the singular first-person pronoun, "I", is capitalized, along with all its contractions such as I'll and I'm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items= int(items1)` will either assign some integer to `items` (if `items1` can be interpreted as an integer by Python) or raise a `ValueError`. In your situation, it's obviously the former case. I'd assume that `items1` is a string representing a single number.

Maybe you'd need something like:

```
...
items1 = self.tableLinhaNova.item(row, column).text()
items = [int(i) for i in items1.split(',')]
...
```

Comment: @ANDRESA But you should check what `items1` actually contains. It might always be a single integer and `for item in items:` loop would be redundant.